# Is there a way to pass a block into Class::new as an argument?

Tags: ruby

It seems like for a vast majority of methods that take blocks, if you have a block, proc, or lambda stored in a variable you can pass it in. For example

```
mapper = -> (foo) { foo * foo }
(1..5).map(&mapper) # => [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

The method `Class::new` can be initialized using a block to create a class, as such:

```
klass = Class.new do
  def foo
    'bar'
  end
end
klass.new.foo # => "bar"
```

However, I cannot do something like this

```
class_body = lambda do
  def foo
    'bar'
  end
end
klass = Class.new(&class_body)
```

I get `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0))`. There is a way around this by doing something like this,

```
klass = Class.new { class_body.call }
klass.new.foo
```

But it seems like this shouldn't be necessary. Is there a more idiomatic way to instantiate a class with a block as an argument other than something like

```
def define_class(&class_body)
  Class.new { class_body.call }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both [the documentation of `Class::new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-c-new) and the error message clearly show, the block is passed one argument [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> ## `new(super_class=Object) { |mod| ... }` → `a_class`
>
> […]
>
> If a block is given, **it is passed the class object**, and the block is evaluated in the context of this class like class_eval.

Also, in the error message you posted:

> ArgumentError (**wrong number** of arguments (**given 1, expected 0**))

The error message is saying that your lambda was passed one argument, but it is expecting none.

The fix is easy: add a parameter to your lambda:

```ruby
class_body = -> * do
  def foo
    'bar'
  end
end

klass = Class.new(&class_body)
```

Or, if you don't absolutely require a lambda, you could use a non-lambda `Proc`:

```ruby
class_body = proc do
  def foo
    'bar'
  end
end

klass = Class.new(&class_body)
```